# Hibernate : Random Exceptions and record not updated during session flush, using saveOrUpdate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ubuntu

I am trying to keep a record updated with the latest time stamp. A while ago I was getting a Exception. Now, I am not getting the exception, but the record does not update on the database.

```
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Duplicate entry '1584034242' for key 'PRIMARY'
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1584034242' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

On line `session.flush();` in finally block.

The record being updated has the same primary key (of a existing record in the DB), but with changed values of two columns, so its **not** a duplicate. I was expecting that `saveOrUpdate` will save me here, and it was working a while back.

```
public void flush(Object dataStore) throws DidNotSaveRequestSomeRandomError {
        Transaction txD;
        Session session;
        session = currentSession();
        if (session.getTransaction() != null && session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            txD = session.getTransaction();
        } else {
            txD = session.beginTransaction();
        }

        try {
            session.saveOrUpdate(dataStore);
        } catch (MappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            txD.commit();
            while (!txD.wasCommitted())
                ;
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            log.error("Unable to store data from " + dataStore.getClass().toString());
            txD.rollback();
            throw new DidNotSaveRequestSomeRandomError(dataStore, feedbackManager);
        } catch (TransactionException e) {
            log.debug("txD state isActive" + txD.isActive() + " txD is participating"
                    + txD.isParticipating());
            log.debug(e);
            txD.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            txD = null;
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Edit :
Did a lot more googleing and found that I need to use dynamic-update in my xml definition to get this to work.

```
<class name="My.Java.Class"
    table="MyTable" dynamic-update="true">
```

Still does not work, I get that duplicate entry. I am not using a update clause, but assuming that saveORUpdate should work. And there should be someway to get it working.

**OR**

Should I catch constraintViolationException and do a forced "update" clause instead ?

Comment: How's is it possible to have same value of primary key of two records? Did you remove primary key and trying to insert? then saveOrUpdate method will not work it will update record as if it finds same primary key value otherwise create new record. Please provide example of your data.

Comment: I dont want 2 records with the same primary key (That is not possible, as you correctly pointed). I am looking to update the existing record.

Comment: @Siddharth did you check my answer.. what you are doing with a while loop with semicolon??

Comment: @Lakshmi yes did not help, sorry.

Comment: @Siddharth s your primary key autogenerated or are you explicitly setting the primary key value in datasource?

Comment: I am explicitly setting the value. It is not auto generated.

Comment: @Siddharth In that case i think save and update wont work try writing an update query specifying your primary key as the attribute in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

flush()
method  just synchronization with the db and then you need to commit or clear the session to see the changes.

And if you do just commit .It automatically flushes and you can see your changes from another session too.

Comment: Do you mean `txD.commit()` just after `session.flush()` ; ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using too much try catch block better do this and what is that **while** loop with a **;** doing it is not needed.

```
 try {
            txD.commit();
            while (!txD.wasCommitted()) ;//this is not needed
        }
```

You can simply do the below:

```
try{
    session = currentSession();
        if (session.getTransaction() != null && session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            txD = session.getTransaction();
        } else {
            txD = session.beginTransaction();
        }

    session.saveOrUpdate(dataStore);
    txD.commit();
   }catch (MappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        log.error("Unable to store data from " + dataStore.getClass().toString());
        txD.rollback();
        throw new DidNotSaveRequestSomeRandomError(dataStore, feedbackManager);
    } catch (TransactionException e) {
        log.debug("txD state isActive" + txD.isActive() + " txD is participating"
                + txD.isParticipating());
        log.debug(e);
        txD.rollback();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        txD = null;
        session.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think hibernate didn't getting your primary key id value,
One thing you can try that in your DataStore bean assign id in getter method of primary key field like

```
String getPrimayValue(String primayValue)
{
    this.primayValue = primayValue;
    return primayValue;
}
```

I was facing same issue before and it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Did a lot more googleing and found that I need to use dynamic-update in my xml definition to get this to work.

```
<class name="My.Java.Class"
    table="MyTable" dynamic-update="true">
```

Comment: just out of curiosity the  dynamic-update="true" only allows hibernate to omit those attributes of a table that are not modified during an update. But as per my knowledge save and update uses the primary key in the where clause to update a record no matter what so setting this attribute should not make any difference as the primary  key will still be on the where clause.

Comment: Still trying to figure it out, will respond in a while.